# Aggregating data to show latest result?

Tags: css-js-aggregation

I'm currently using the Elasticsearch Connector to get my data from Elasticsearch for displaying. I've managed to set up some basic pages and display the data successfully, but am now looking for a way to group it.
for example, if I have several results but they are all from the same server address, I would like to group them by server and show only the lastest input.

I've looked through options on views, and the aggregator module but can't seem to manage it.
Is this something that's possible, and I've missed?
Or is that not possible in drupal anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In Views you can group by a particular field if the display allows fields (table, not teaser, etc). Under the Settings for Table for example you can choose the field to group the results:

[image]

The field has to be present in the list of Fields, but can be excluded from display if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation query in elastic search to group data.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html